# Cannot update textbox on Access form

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

I have a form `frm_Manage_Demand` with two subforms: `frm_Manage_Demand_Sub` and `frm_Manage_Demand_Bottom_Sub`.  I use the subforms to display the data from `tbl_Manage_Demand`.  The reason I use two subforms is because there are two many fields to display on the screen in one form.

The need to allow the user to update the last two fields on the form plus an `unbound textbox` that is populated when the form is loaded.

I am unable to get the form to allow a user to enter data in the two fields plus the `unbound textbox`.  All fields are set to `Enabled = Yes` and `Locked = No`.  The main form has no record source.   It attributes for `Allow Edit, Allow Additions, Allow Deletions` are all set to `Yes`.

The record source for the two subforms is `tbl_Manage_Demand`.

I created a new test form based on the `tbl_Manage_Demand` and I can update all fields just fine.

Any hints to solve my problem is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that an unknown section of the code turned the control `AllowEdits` to `No`.  So after the `frm_Manage_Bottom_Sub` form loaded I changed the control using `Forms![frm_Manage_Demand]![frm_Manage_Demand_Bottom_Sub].Form.AllowEdits = True`